# Decreasing magnitude of spherical centroid

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, inequalities, convexity, spherical-geometry

Let $\sigma$ be the uniform measure on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$. For any region $R\subset \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$, let $X_R$ be a random variable which is uniformly distributed across $R$. We have $$E(X_R)=\frac{1}{\sigma(R)}\int_R xd\sigma (x)$$
Is it true that if $R\subset S\subset \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ are convex then $|E(X_S)|\le |E(X_R)|$?

To start, I'll state a claim.

**Claim**: If $T\subset \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ with $G=E(X_T)/|E(X_T)|$ and $B$ is a small ball $B$ disjoint from $T$, then $|E(X_{T\cup B})|<|E(X_T)|$ iff $B$ is further (by dot product) from $G$ than the rest of $T$, on average. That is, for $b\in B$

$$G\cdot b<\frac{1}{\sigma(T)}\int_T G\cdot xd\sigma(x)$$

**Proof of claim**: Note that for positive numbers $a,b,c,d$ satisfying $a/b<c/d$,

$$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a+c}{b+d}< \frac{c}{d}$$

Also, when $B$ is small, $$\frac{E(X_{T\cup B})}{|E(X_{T\cup B})|}\approx \frac{E(X_T)}{|E(X_T)|}=:G$$ so that $|E(X_T)|=G\cdot E(X_T)$ and $|E(X_{T\cup B})|\approx G\cdot E(X_{T\cup B})$. Expanding these out, the statement $|E(X_{T\cup B})|<|E(X_T)|$ becomes

\begin{align*}
\frac{\int_T G\cdot x d\sigma(x)+\int_B G\cdot x d\sigma(x)}{\sigma(T)+\sigma(B)}<&\frac{\int_T G\cdot x d\sigma(x)}{\sigma(T)}\\
\frac{\int_B G\cdot xd\sigma(x)}{\sigma(B)}<&\frac{\int_T G\cdot x d\sigma(x)}{\sigma(T)}\\
G\cdot b <& \frac{\int_T G\cdot xd\sigma(x)}{\sigma(T)}
\end{align*}

All the steps are reversible, so we have both directions of iff. One direction still works for any small region $B$ disjoint from $T$, but the other direction fails as the magnitude $|\int_B xd\sigma(x)|/\sigma(B)$ can be significantly less than $1$.

The convexity requirement is not conducive to unions with balls, but the statement is not true if we drop convexity.

Seems like a start?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok great, hopefully my post is more readable now!

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a "convex region on the sphere"?

Comment: To be a counterexample, we need two convex subsets of a sphere… I’m not sure how you go about getting those.

Comment: $T\subset \mathbb{S}^d$ is convex if it is the intersection of closed hemispheres. A hemisphere centered at a point C is the set of points within geodesic distance $\pi/2$ from $C$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but infinitesimally it would mean that if we have two symmetric convex bodies $A\subset B$ in $R^{d-1}$, then the mean value of $|x|^2$ over $A$ is not greater than that over $B$. Now consider a thin diamond shape in $R^2$ and an even thinner rectangle inscribed into it along its big diagonal.

Comment: In the case of symmetric infinitesimal bodies, there is a center $G$ in the sphere so that $$|E(X_A)|=G\cdot E(X_A)=E(\cos GX_A)\approx 1-0.5E(x^2)$$ where $x$ is the random arc length from G to a uniform point in A. Indeed, the tendency for $E(x^2)$ to increase as a small convex set grows is confirmation of my conjecture. Is this how you meant? Thanks!

Comment: I meant that the pair of sets I mentioned gives a counterexample to the infinitesimal version.

Comment: Please, help me understand. Why are you looking at the mean of $x^2$? The question is about the magnitude of the mean of $x$

Comment: Of course, I have been meaning $|x|^2$ every time I write $x^2$. Sorry, I’m rushing on my phone.

Comment: Erm... Didn't you write yourself that $|E(X_A)|\approx 1−0.5E(|x|^2)$ ?

Comment: Yes, so if $A\subset B$, symmetric convex, and $x$ is the random arc length from the center, then $E|x|^2$ will be smaller for $A$, giving bigger $|EX|$. This is in accord with the hypothesis, not a counterexample. Put another way, $|EX_A|$ approaches $1$ as $A$ shrinks, and $|EX_A|<1$.

Comment: Aaron, that's getting a bit tiresome. Yes, if it were smaller for $A$, it would be in accord with the hypothesis, but did you bother to compute that quantity for the planar regions I mentioned? I believe that the inequality for them is in the opposite direction if they are thin enough. :-)

Comment: Yes, I had computed your example. I will try again. Thank you for your patience. Ah, I do keep getting things flipped, as in your description of your counterexample.

Comment: I got (assuming that the big diagonal is $[-1,1]$) $\int_0^1x^2\,dx=1/3$ for the rectangle and $(\int_0^1(1-x)x^2\,dx)/(\int_0^1(1-x)\,dx)=1/6$ for the diamond (the contribution of the $y$-coordinate is negligible in both cases). What did you get? Note that we can inscribe both the rectangle into the diamond and the diamond into the rectangle, so it doesn't really matter what the numbers are as long as they are different.

Comment: @fedja : Can you post your nice counterexample as a formal answer, with enough details about "infinitesimally", just to make everyone happy? :-)

Comment: @fedja: I now agree with your answers. Thanks - I would give you the bounty if you post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\SSS}{\mathbb S}\newcommand{\tS}{\tilde S}\newcommand{\tR}{\tilde R}$This is to detail and formalize the nice counterexample outlined in fedja's comment.

First, let us recapitulate the counterexample informally. Let $d=3$. Consider the point $P:=(0,0,1)$ on the unit sphere $\SSS_2$. In the plane $\Pi:=\{(x,y,z)\in\R^3\colon z=1\}$, tangent to $\SSS_2$ at $P$, take a small thin diamond shape $\tS$ centered at $P$. Take then a very thin rectangle $\tR$ inscribed into the diamond $\tS$ along its bigger diagonal. Let $R$ and $S$ be the images of $\tR$ and $\tS$, respectively, under the
central projection (with the center at the origin) onto the sphere $\SSS_2$.

By symmetry, the centroids $EX_R$ and $EX_S$ of $R$ and $S$ will then be on the $z$-axis, so that $EX_R=(0,0,z_R)$ and $EX_S=(0,0,z_S)$ for some $z_R$ and $z_S$ in the interval $(0,1)$, and hence $|EX_R|=z_R$ and $|EX_S|=z_S$. Note that $z_R$ and $z_S$ are $\approx1$. So, it makes sense to compare $1-z_R$ and $1-z_S$.

For points $(x,y,z)\in\SSS_2$ close to $P$, we have $1-z=1-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\sim(x^2+y^2)/2$. So, comparing the averages of $z$ over $R$ and $S$ is asymptotically equivalent to comparing the averages of $x^2+y^2$ over $R$ and $S$, and hence to comparing the averages of $x^2+y^2$ over the flat regions $\tR$ and $\tS$, since the central projection from the sphere $\SSS_2$ onto the plane $\Pi$ distorts the lengths negligibly near $P$.

It remains to compare the averages of $x^2+y^2$ over the flat regions $\tR$ and $\tS$, which is straightforward.

---

Let us now formalize the reasoning. For $h\downarrow0$, consider the diamond shape
\begin{equation*}
    \tS:=\Big\{(x,y,1)\in\R^3\colon \frac{|x|}h+\frac{|y|}{h^2}\le1\Big\}  
\end{equation*}
in the plane $\Pi$ and its narrow part
\begin{equation*}
    \tR:=\Big\{(x,y,1)\in\R^3\colon \frac{|x|}h+\frac{|y|}{h^2}\le1,\, |y|\le h^3\Big\}.   
\end{equation*}
Let $R$ and $S$ be the images of $\tR$ and $\tS$, respectively, under the
central projection (with the center at the origin) onto the sphere $\SSS_2$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    S=\big\{r(x,y)\colon(x,y)\in\rho_S\big\}\quad\text{and}\quad    R=\big\{r(x,y)\colon(x,y)\in\rho_R\big\}, 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    r(x,y):=\frac{(x,y,1)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}},  
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \rho_S:=\Big\{(x,y)\in\R^2\colon\frac{|x|}h+\frac{|y|}{h^2}\le1\Big\},  
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \rho_R:=\Big\{(x,y)\in\R^2\colon\frac{|x|}h+\frac{|y|}{h^2}\le1,\,|y|\le h^3\Big\}.   
\end{equation*}
So, the regions $S$ and $R$ on the sphere are parametrized by parameters $x,y$, with $(x,y)\in\rho_S$ and $(x,y)\in\rho_R$, respectively.

With this parametrization, the spherical area element is
\begin{equation*}
    dA(x,y)=\|r_x(x,y)\times r_y(x,y)\|\,dx\,dy \\ 
    =\frac{dx\,dy}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{3/2}}\sim dx\,dy
\end{equation*}
for $(x,y)\in\rho_S$, where $r_x$ and $r_y$ are the partial derivatives of the vector function $r$ with respect to $x$ and $y$; $\times$ is the cross product; and $\|\cdot\|$ is the length. This result for $dA(x,y)$ is also easy to obtain geometrically.

Introducing the $z$-coordinate of $r(x,y)$,
\begin{equation*}
    Z(x,y):=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}},
\end{equation*}
we see that
\begin{equation*}
    1-Z(x,y)\sim\frac{x^2+y^2}2
\end{equation*}
for $(x,y)\in\rho_S$ and hence for $(x,y)\in\rho_R$.

So,
\begin{equation*}
    \iint_{\rho_S}dA(x,y)
    \sim\iint_{\rho_S}dx\,dy=2h^3,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \iint_{\rho_S}(1-Z(x,y))dA(x,y)
    \sim\frac12\,\iint_{\rho_S}(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy \\ 
    =\frac16\,h^5(1+h^2)\sim\frac{h^5}6, 
\end{equation*}
whence
\begin{equation*}
    1-z_S=\dfrac{\iint_{\rho_S}(1-Z(x,y))dA(x,y)}{\iint_{\rho_S}dA(x,y)}
    \sim\frac{h^5}{6}/(2h^3)=\frac{h^2}{12}. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}

Also,
\begin{equation*}
    \iint_{\rho_R}dA(x,y)\sim4\int_0^{h^3}dy\,\int_0^{h-O(h^2)} dx\sim4h^4,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    \iint_{\rho_R}(1-Z(x,y))dA(x,y)
    \sim\frac12\,\iint_{\rho_R}(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy \\ 
    =\frac42\,\int_0^{h^3}dy\,\int_0^{h-O(h^2)}(x^2+y^2)\, dx\sim\frac{2h^6}3,  
\end{equation*}
whence
\begin{equation*}
    1-z_R=\dfrac{\iint_{\rho_R}(1-Z(x,y))dA(x,y)}{\iint_{\rho_R}dA(x,y)}
    \sim\frac{2h^6}3/(4h^4)=\frac{h^2}6. \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}

By \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}, for all small enough $h>0$ we have $1-z_R>1-z_S$, that is $z_S>z_R$, that is $|E(X_S)|>|E(X_R)|$, which disproves the conjecture $|E(X_S)|\le|E(X_R)|$.

Comment: Thanks Iosif for filling it out! I guess you could say that this had to do with the difference in shapes. Skinny diamonds are more concentrated around the middle than skinny rectangles. Originally, I had thought the statement to be true when $S$ and $R$ are both spherical simplices, and this would be nearly as satisfying as only requiring convex. Can you think of any counterexamples involving spherical simplices, or perhaps a good idea for how to proceed with a proof? I've thought about the problem long enough and keep running into something like Simpson's paradox as I'm averaging. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith : I guess similar ideas can work for spherical simplices, but I have not looked into that. Do you want to post such a question, about spherical simplices, separately?

Answer (score 0):

Just take a skinny convex region on a high dimensional sphere. The (spherical) centroid of the region will be close to the boundary. Add a point outside the region but still close, then take the convex hull. In high dimensions, that will mostly only add points that are still close to the centroid. From your claim, it should increase the magnitude.